# SFTP using public key authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ssh, sftp, public-key-encryption

How to send a CSV file to SFTP by using public key authentication?

What is the procedure to do it?

Comment: What language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Using [SSH.NET library](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) in C#:

```csharp
const string hostname = "example.com";
const string username = "username";
const string privateKey = @"C:\mykey";
const string sourcePath = @"C:\local\path\file.txt";
const string targetPath = "/remote/path/file.txt";

AuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod =
    new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(username,
        new PrivateKeyFile[]{new PrivateKeyFile(privateKey)});

ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(hostname, username, authenticationMethod);

using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
{
    client.Connect();

    using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        client.UploadFile(fileStream, targetPath, true);
    }

    client.Disconnect();
}
```